# ReactNative - build failed : http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. 501 HTTPS Required

Tags: react-native

As of January 15, 2020 my react native build is failing with the error:

> http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. 
>   Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required

Answer (score 0):

Solution: 
Update build.gradle

from:

> http://central.maven.org/maven2/

To:

> https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

see ref:
https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334